# Atomic queries in MySQL/MyISAM

Tags: mysql, myisam

Suppose I want to select a maximum value from a table using MySQL w/ MyISAM engine and then insert a new record <del>with this maximum + 1</del> based on this value (after applying a transformation to it). I don't want any other transactions happening at the same time that will read the same maximum value and then try to insert the same new record.

How do I prevent this from happening?

Do I need to [LOCK](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html) the entire table, or what?

---

To be clear, I'm fairly certain I can't use `AUTO_INCREMENT` here unless I can redefine the operation it performs to something considerably more complex than "plus one".

Comment: Sounds like `AUTO_INCREMENT` could be helpful to you

Comment: @AlainCollins: This is a simple example. It's a bit more than just adding 1 and inserting back into the same column. I am using AIs where I can.

Answer (score 3):

```
LOCK TABLES `tbl` WRITE;
INSERT INTO `tbl` (`id`, `foo`) SELECT MAX(`id`)+1, 'bar' FROM `tbl`;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

But you should use `AUTO_INCREMENT` if it's a standard primary key / ID type field.

Comment: So "yes", I do need to lock the table. Or just write-lock? Why would I  not need to read-lock it? If another query *reads* the maximum value and later tries to do the insert (after the write-lock is removed), would that not cause problems?

Comment: According to the mysql docs on write locks: "Only the session that holds the lock can access the table. No other session can access it until the lock is released."

Answer (score 1):

Let the database do the work for you so you don't have to worry about this. Use the [auto_increment](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) feature that's already built in.

Comment: I said "a maximum value". Never said I was using this as the PK. Also, I'm doing transformations on it too.

Comment: @Mark: There's no requirement that the auto incremented column be the PK.

Comment: As I understand it, I'm only allowed 1 AI per table, and I've already got one. But again, this is besides the point.

Comment: @Mark: Would have been helpful if you had stated these requirements and restrictions in your original question.

Comment: I apologize. The question was about atomic queries, not workarounds or alternatives to a very specific use-case, but I should have been more clear about my intentions.